# Example of a Complex Power Series That Converges Given Certain Properties

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm currently trying to answer the following complex analysis question: "give an example of a power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ with radius of convergence $2$ which converges at some $z_0 \in \{z: |z|=2\}$ and diverges at some $z_1 \in \{z: |z|=2\}$".

This is what I currently have:
"Consider the following series: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^nz^n$.
Then we have that the radius of convergence is:
$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|  
=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{(1/2)^n}{(1/2)^{n+1}}|  
=|\frac{1}{1/2}|$
$=|2|$
$=2$.
Let $z_1=2$.
Then we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^n(2)^n$
$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(1/2\cdot2)^n$
$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(1)^n$
$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}1$, which diverges."

My question is how to find a $z_0 \in \{z: |z|=2\}$ where my series converges. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since $\left|(\frac{1}{2})^nz^n\right|=1\not \to 0$ when $|z|=2$, there is no such $z$ for which the sum converges

Comment: Should I create a different series then?

Comment: Yes - for example try to find one with conditional convergence but not absolute convergence

Comment: What should my $a_n$ portion be? I'm having trouble coming up with a series with a radius of convergence of $2$ that isn't $(1/2)^n$.

Comment: Take a power series with radius of convergence $1$ and multiply by $(1/2)^n$.

Comment: Would $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)^n}{1+n}z^n$ work because the radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1+n}$ is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{n2^n}$ for $n > 0$. Then $R = 2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 2^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, whereas $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (-2)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ converges.